# How do you convert a multiple arrays of string inside json into csv using python?

Tags: python, json, csv, data-science

How do you convert a nested json of multiple arrays into csv tabular structure using python?
see the complete json [here](https://spaces.hightail.com/space/yoz24Fi6pB)

CODE :

```
import json
import csv

f = open('cost_drilldown_data.json')

data = json.load(f)
s=csv.writer(open('costdrillwittime_storage4.csv','w'))
s.writerow(["filter","cost","value","cost","subvalue","cost","res_id","cost","tot_cost","metdata"])
i=0
d = []
for breakdown in data['breakdown']:
    #for time in data['time']:
        for storage in data['storage']:
             if storage not in d:

                for values in breakdown['values']:

                    if 'subvalues' in values:
                         for subvalues in values['subvalues']:
                    #for i in range(0,len(data)):
                            s.writerow([breakdown['filter'],breakdown["cost"],values['value'],values['cost'],
                            subvalues["subvalue"],subvalues["cost"],storage['resource_id'],storage['cost'],
                            storage['total_cost'],storage['metadata']])

                    else :
                         s.writerow([breakdown['filter'],"","",values['value'],values['cost']])
```

ACTUAL OUTPUT OF THE ABOVE CODE:

> filter,cost,value,cost,subvalue,cost,res_id,cost,tot_cost,metdata
>
> tags,5517.734,Name,462.62,BizOps-VM-20,227.576,i-048e0bfa74ac9cf78,25.047,25.801000000000002,{u'name': u'BizOps0424001'}
>
> tags,5517.734,Name,462.62,,70.358,i-048e0bfa74ac9cf78,25.047,25.801000000000002,{u'name':
>   u'BizOps0424001'}
>
> tags,5517.734,Name,462.62,BizOps01,60.188,i-048e0bfa74ac9cf78,25.047,25.801000000000002,{u'name':
>   u'BizOps0424001'}...

its repeating the values of meta data again and again and also repeating the NAME after wards.

how to make print the values only once and differnt values only as per the counts.

see the full csv file [here](https://spaces.hightail.com/space/U5pEvcPcUJ)

> **TOTALLY EDITED CODE AFTER ANKUSH's HELP:**

```
import json
import csv

f = open('cost_drilldown_data.json')
data = json.load(f)


s=csv.writer(open('googletry1.csv','w'))


breakdown = data['breakdown']
storage = data['storage']
filter_list = []            #first column
filter_cost_list = []       #second column
value_list = []             #third column
cost_list = []              #fourth column
subValue_list = []          #fifth col
subvalueCost_list = []      #sixth col
resID_list = []             #seventh col
storageCost_list = []       #eighth col
totalCost_list = []         #ninth col
metadata_list = []          #tenth col

s.writerow(["filter_list","filter_cost_list","value_list","cost_list","subValue_list","subvalueCost_list","resID_list","storageCost_list","totalCost_list","metadata_list"])

for eachBreakdown in breakdown:
    filter_list.append(eachBreakdown['filter'])
    filter_cost_list.append(['cost'])
    valuesArr = eachBreakdown['values']
    for eachValues in valuesArr:
        value_list.append(eachValues['value'])
        cost_list.append(eachValues['cost'])
        if 'subvalues' in eachValues:
            subValueArr = eachValues['subvalues']
        for eachSubValueArr in subValueArr:
            subValue_list.append(eachSubValueArr['subvalue'])
            subvalueCost_list.append(eachSubValueArr['cost'])

                    #s.writerow([breakdown['filter'],breakdown["cost"],values['value'],values['cost'],
                    #subvalues["subvalue"],subvalues["cost"],storage['resource_id'],storage['cost'],
                    #storage['total_cost'],storage['metadata'],storage['volume_cost'],storage['provider']])

            s.writerow([eachBreakdown['filter'],eachBreakdown['cost'],eachValues['value'],eachValues['cost'],
            eachSubValueArr['subvalue'],eachSubValueArr['cost']])

for eachStorage in storage:
    resID_list.append(eachStorage['resource_id'])
    storageCost_list.append(eachStorage['cost'])
    totalCost_list.append(eachStorage['total_cost'])
    metadata_list.append([eachStorage['metadata']])


    s.writerow([eachStorage['resource_id']])


now i am getting challenge in printing the resource id to the side of the subvalue cost: I am getting csv file as :
enter code here
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate with an example. The data you mentioned is 10 elements in it. Not sure which one are you talking about.

Comment: @AnkushRathi, please find the python code pls correct me the code.and when you open the link you will fnd the file pls download it and see

Comment: Your looping is wrong that's why you're getting the same tag,cost etc values in the output. Can you explain what exactly you want in output?

Comment: @AnkushRathi, yes how to modify the loop,Will explain what i need in csv is: i need some specific datas like values and its cost from the json multiple arrays.
EG:
Filter cost"value","cost","subvalue","cost","res_id","cost","tot_cost","metdata"
tag      5877   .. .. .   ..   ..    ...   ...

Comment: the thing is your data does not have equal number of elements. What i mean is there are 14 elemets in `breakdow` and 26 or so in `breakdown[values]`. I will be able to help you only if you explain it clearly.

Comment: @AnkushRathi, please see the edited answers, what is the actual problem is i will paste the csv file in link it get repeated again and agin for some values. please revert once you see the csv

Comment: @AnkushRathi, please see the csv link it prints the values again and again

Comment: @AnkushRathi, you there? can you revert if possible

Comment: i ran your code already and i can see the output too. Can i know what you actually want as output ? Because this current output is obviously not what you want.

Comment: @AnkushRathi, thanks for running it , see actually what i expect is 
i need the all filter values in one column and its cost in another column and inside that we subvalues with subvalue and cost till this i am able to print >
But after that comes the time array with data and cost and next comes storage array where i want to pick only the res_id and the cost then same for the remaining arrays.
but im stuck in doing the for loop for it as when i do it gets repeated again and again.like it goes around and around 
I will be very greatful if you help on this please!!!!!

Comment: @AnkushRathi, sorry for late reply.and can you try any different code using pandas and how do yu iterate and make a generic pytho code. just give me some idea if you dont have time!! pls

Comment: @AnkushRathi, you there can you pls try as much as possible!!! pls !

Comment: :p hold on buddy...its not the end of the world...will get back...peace ..//.

Comment: @AnkushRathi, sorry !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you posted in not clear, though I have tried to understand it. In the [json](https://spaces.hightail.com/space/yoz24Fi6pB/files/fi-5b87bce2-e26f-4c0f-afe2-182471fc2213/fv-fd16ab4f-b15d-4dd4-9d0a-1284b123560f/cost_drilldown_data.json) you are working on, the objects are irregularly structured. What i mean is, there are not the same number of objects in the json for every key element. You also never mentioned what exactly you want in case of a data miss.

Find the code below. I have managed to get all the values of columns in a list. You may print them to see. Happy to help.

```
import json

f = open('cost_drilldown_data.json')
data = json.load(f)

breakdown = data['breakdown']
storage = data['storage']
filter_list = []            #first column
filter_cost_list = []       #second column
value_list = []             #third column
cost_list = []              #fourth column
subValue_list = []          #fifth col
subvalueCost_list = []      #sixth col
resID_list = []             #seventh col
storageCost_list = []       #eighth col
totalCost_list = []         #ninth col
metadata_list = []          #tenth col

for eachBreakdown in breakdown:
    filter_list.append(eachBreakdown['filter'])
    filter_cost_list.append(['cost'])
    valuesArr = eachBreakdown['values']
    for eachValues in valuesArr:
        value_list.append(eachValues['value'])
        cost_list.append(eachValues['cost'])
        if 'subvalues' in eachValues:
            subValueArr = eachValues['subvalues']
        for eachSubValueArr in subValueArr:
            subValue_list.append(eachSubValueArr['subvalue'])
            subvalueCost_list.append(eachSubValueArr['cost'])

for eachStorage in storage:
    resID_list.append(eachStorage['resource_id'])
    storageCost_list.append(eachStorage['cost'])
    totalCost_list.append(eachStorage['total_cost'])
    metadata_list.append([eachStorage['metadata']])
```

Comment: Thanks for your great effort it really helped me a lot,
But now i have one challenge like as you mentioned two separate for loops
when i use writerows it gets printed downwards not i sidewards for the eachstorage column how can i wite the code to print it alternatively

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/5585424/ankush-rathi,,
Please see the edited code made to print in csv how to make print the reource id paralley

Comment: now i made to print parallel by passing the storage for loop before the s.writerow.ie after the 1st for loop end.
BUT HAVE TO SEE WHY ITS GETTING REPEATED

Comment: Can you guide me on how to stop printing the resources _id values and their cost which is repeating.
Will paste the output csv came for me

Comment: this thread is going too long for no reason...mail me here- rathiankush123@gmail.com